# What are the existing open-source Python WxWidgets designers?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

What are the usable tools?
I am aware of wxformbuilder and wxGlade, but none of them seems to be complete yet.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few of the most popular wxPython related GUI builders:

- Boa Constructor (mostly dead)
- wxGlade
- wxFormBuilder
- XRCed
- wxDesigner (not FOSS)
- Dabo - one of their videos shows a way to interactively design an app...

I personally just use a Python IDE to hand code my applications. My current favorite IDE is Wing.

Comment: The op was looking for open-source applications -wxDesigner is not foss.

Comment: Yeah, but I thought I should mentioned it since the wxPython wiki does. Besides, sometimes the paid programs work best.

Comment: Sure no harm in mentioning it, but I think It is a little misleading not to have mentioned in your answer that it is a commercial application.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for them too and sadly I've come up empty handed.  I used to like Boa Constructor and PythonCard back in the day but both projects seem to have stalled.  There is an attempt to get PythonCard going again @ http://trac.medianix.org/wiki/Pycard ; the site was down when I checked last but the [mailing list seemed moderately active](http://trac.medianix.org/lists/pycard-users/archive/).  [Dabo](http://dabodev.com/)'s another actively-developed option.

Comment: PyCard site is still down and I'am afraid it doesn't exist anymore as the latest PyCard code release is from 2006 and latest mail on mailing list is from jan/2009. Dabo is active, not a real GUI designer but database oriented and seems good.

Answer (score 1):

afaik... none. I'll follow the answers to see if someone has one and try it of course but I'm not convinced this will be THAT useful. When using wxPython, you usually work with sizers (at least I think the results are better) so you don't really need to "place" the controls on the frame and I think a GUI "design" would be longer to do. The only part where I think it could have some interest is to fill atributes for the controls but a good auto-complete with wx (or a good cheat sheet or a "template class" with all the options you use) solves the problem in my opinion. I stopped seeking for a GUI designer for wx after trying Pydev that auto-completes wx very nicely (a lot better than everything I tried before... and that's a lot!).

Comment: wxformbuilder is based on the sizers, but it is not complete, the interface still need some work, many widgets are not yet included in the tool, and it just recently started support for python.

Comment: Yes, but not very recent, it's a nightly beta from more than a year now, so I'm not sure if it will be completed some day in a close/medium future. I didn't try it because I have the impression the developpers stopped (at least posting and answering), not sure about coding. Unfortunately, it's the same on almost all visual designers I've seen for wxPython... Anyways, if all the controls that work in C++ work in Python, the list is far from bad already, even if it will not get updated soon but what about next wxPython releases...